# Including headers in subfolders

Tags: c++, cmake, header-files, include-path

I work on a C++ program which I develop on my personal Ubuntu 15.04 machine which eventually has to run on openSUSE 13.1 at work. To make it work on both systems I carefully chose the libraries and the versions to use.

Now I have a problem with the includes. I want to use Qwt 6, which is available on both distributions. The location of the header files differs, though. On Debian they are at `/usr/include/qwt/qwt_*.h` but on openSUSE they are at `/usr/include/qwt6/qwt_*.h`. My code currently has `#include <qwt/qwt_plot.h>`. This does not work on openSUSE since I would have to insert that `6` there.

The easiest solution that I currently see is just including either directory using CMake and then just writing `#include <qwt_plot.h>` in the source code. However, I think that this is not a really nice solution since those subdirectoryies of `/usr/include` are there to provide namespaces. Just adding all directories to the include path will mangle those together and might even lead to conflicts.

Is there a nice way to solve this?

In fairness: This is for a project I am paid to work on.

Comment: you could do tricks with symbolic links, for example. Which compiler do you use ? Perhaps it will help to define which directories that compiler is to use and then change from #include <qwt/qwt_plot to #include "qwt_plot"

Comment: or you could do something rather ugly with the preprocessor, like shown there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178946/using-define-to-include-another-file-in-c-c

Comment: @Marged: Symbolic links would requite root access to the `/usr/include` directory, which I do not want to force them to give me for this. I use g++ on both distrubtions, 4.9 on Ubuntu and 4.8 on openSUSE. The macros do not look like an improvement compared to just `<qwt_plot.h>`.

Comment: The macros would allow you to specify the prefix to use in front of the header file. Also the symbolic links could be created in the directory you run cmake in: create a symbolic link named "pointertoqwtinclude" and have that one point to the /usr/include directory. Then simply #include "pointertoqwtinclude/stuff.h"

Comment: @Marged: The symlink trick would either require me to add the directory of the symlink (somewhere in `~`) to the `<…>` search path or include those files with `"…"`. Both seems like a hack to me :-/.

Comment: if a "hack" or "creative solution" which is pushing the borders is off limits I suggest you use the autoconf style solution below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CMake you can configure platform checks like you could for autoconf. The idea is that you include a `config.h` file that always exists but use tools to generate that file in each platform. You can check how [here](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Write_Platform_Checks) but as a summary you can have a `config.h.in` file with the checks you want to make and use in your headers.

```
#cmakedefine HAVE_QWT_H
#cmakedefine HAVE_QWT6_H
```

You then have CMake check if the headers are present and process that file into a final `config.h` file. In the `CMakeLists.txt` file you could have the following.

```
INCLUDE (CheckIncludeFiles)

CHECK_INCLUDE_FILES (qwt/qwt_plot.h HAVE_QWT_H)
CHECK_INCLUDE_FILES (qwt6/qwt_plot.h HAVE_QWT6_H)
CONFIGURE_FILE(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/config.h.in ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/config.h)
```

Finally, in your headers, you include the `config.h` and use the macros to conditionally include one header or another.

```
// always included
#include "config.h"

// conditionally include headers based one macros from config.h
#ifdef HAVE_QWT_H
#include <qwt/qwt_plot.h>
#elseif HAVA_QWT6_H
#include <qwt6/qwt_plot.h>
#else
#error QWT headers required and not present in supported locations
#endif
```

Comment: Thank you, I see where this is going. It will just lead to a proliferation of those macros in my sources files. Luckily this does not need to scale to a third distribution or even a different platform, but I do not really to put all those macros into my headers :-/.

Comment: Yes, it's a mess. I nevertheless remember that CMake is part of a 3rd or 4th generation of tools trying to make that task easier. :)