# Include file read from terminal into function using #include

Tags: c++, command-line

I have written a code which reads in mathematical functions from a text file which are in a C++ compatible format and applies mathematical operations to them. This is a brief summary of the code. I am aware that #include is a preprocessor directive so once the contents of the file have been read in it compiles the code via a bash script each time.

```
double myfunc(long double x){
   return
   #include "/.../filename"
}

int main{
   "Maths stuff happens here"
}
```

This works as intended, but I want to be able to speed the process up and read the filename from the terminal rather than entering it into the script each time. To do this I tried using the following:

```
int g_argc;
char **g_argv;

void process_command_()
{
   filename=argv[1]
}

double myfunc(long double x){
   return
   #include filename
}

int main{
   "Maths stuff happens here"
}
```

It was somewhat of a stretch to think this would work, but I am unsure of how to read the filename from the terminal into my function as though I had typed it in myself due to the function being outside of int main(). I have looked around StackExchange and have found similar problems but none of the solutions has worked for my case.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

*Edit for clarity* This code is a numerical integration code which takes a very large integrand as input from a text file and the integration is done using the CUBA library. I moved the process from Maple into C++ to get a speed and accuracy increase. The script works wonderfully and can replicate known values ~ 400 times faster than what Maple/Mathematica can do.

Comment: This isn't how C++ works **at all**.  What is the problem you're trying to solve?  You need to step back and reevaluate the situation.

Comment: Doing an `#include ...` in function-scope is almost certainly a bad idea for whatever reason. Nonetheless, Perhaps, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3179218/1621391) may be relevant - Then you can control the MACRO using some compiler switch

Comment: It is a numerical integration routine which originally was done in Maple/Mathematica but I needed a speed increase, so converted the integrand from Maple into a C++ compatible format and input this file into a C++ routine using the CUBA library. It does provide an enourmous speed increase, I just wanted to speed the calculation process up by automating with a bash script.

Comment: Are you *sure* this is the only way to get a C++ function from your numerical integration library? See if you can find part of the library that takes some input and returns an object with `double operator()(double)` defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WhiZTiM's comment/link made me realise this is a really silly question, so apologies for wasting your time. What I want can be done in the bash script. I just define a placeholder in the `main.cpp`

```
double myfunc(long double x){
   return
   #include <filename>
}
```

Next I put together a simple bash script to *copy the `main.cpp` run file to the directory where the input .txt file is* and using `sed`'s find and replace command it switches the `filename` in `main.cpp` for the actual file which is taken from the terminal:

```
input_file=( "$PWD/${@}" )
cp ${HOME}/.../main.cpp $PWD
sed -i "s|filename|${input_file}|g" main.cpp
```

And then compile and run commands at the end of the script.

Thank you for all your help with this question. I can't believe I didn't see the solution was so simple.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the easiest way for you would be this.

```
double myfunc(long double x){
   return
   #include MY_FILENAME
}
```

Then when you the compiler in `process_command()`, pass it an additional argument:

```
"-DMY_FILENAME=/path/to/your/file"
```

This is a string you need to build out of `argv[1]` or whatever stores your filename.

If you invoke a bash script that invokes the compiler, you need to pass your filename as an argument to the script, and arrange for the script to pass it along with `-DMY_FILENAME=` to the compiler itself.