# Is it possible to typedef a preprocessor directive?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, typedef

Having recently began my studies of C, I have read about `typedef` and I understand that `typedef` is a alias name of an existing type.

Is it possible therefore to `typedef` a preprocessor directive? For example,

```
typedef #include I;
```

to be able to later do

```
I <stdio.h>
```

instead of

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Comment: The preprocessor and C are really separate things without knowledge of each other. So no, that's not possible.

Comment: Preprocessing precede compiling.

Comment: XY problem. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: means can I do that like,  I <stdio.h> instead of #include <stdio.h>

Comment: `error: unknown type name ‘include’`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I read this (intriguing and well-put) question as the OP merely asking about potential wider uses of their first-encountered `typedef`. I don't think it relates to a specific problem.

Comment: @Mahendra: I don't see good reasons to type `I <stdio.h>` instead of `#include <stdio.h>`. But if you absolutely need that, you can *generate* the C code and use something *else* (like [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp)...)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thank you for edited.

Comment: @Mahendra: next time you ask something here, don't comment your own question, but edit it to improve it.

Comment: read about the stages of compilation in C. Preprocessor runs before compiler so how can it replaces `#include`? Moreover `typedef` doesn't replace text and just defines a type alias

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using #define to include another file in C++/C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178946/using-define-to-include-another-file-in-c-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost answered this yourself: `typedef` is used to alias an existing *type*. It is not a crude text substitution mechanism. (Pithily put, one use for it is that is saves you from having to write `struct` all over the place: see [typedef struct vs struct definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675351/typedef-struct-vs-struct-definitions))

But a *preprocessor directive* like `#include` is **not** a type, so it can't be used in the way you want.

Note also that for each *translation unit*, the preprocessing stage finishes before any compilation begins. Your idea looks reliant on the compiler interacting with the preprocessor. The language is not set up that way.

As a final remark, note that the `typedef` mechanism is substantially different in C and C++. In C, all the `typedefs` are injected into a separate *namespace*. See [understanding C namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793952/understanding-c-namespaces). This is all pretty complex stuff, and I've introduced a fair number of terms here, which I've *italicised*. Get to grips with the basics first.

Answer (score 2):

Nope. as others have pointed out, pre-processor runs before compiler, and probably does not do anything special with that line (because it does not start with `#`, though you could use `#define` to change this).

Furthermore, you can't use macros for pre-processor directives. If you could, you could write `#define I #include`, but you can't, won't work. And even if you could, you definitely shouldn't (unless you were writing some intentionally obfuscated code or doing source code layout art or whatever), that'd be considered bad code by just about anybody.

If there is something you actually want to achieve (instead of just being curious or wanting to save typing), you could ask about your actual problem.

Answer (score 2):

As I commented, you should work to make your C code *readable* by others (including yourself in 6 months from now). So using `I <stdio.h>` instead of `#include <stdio.h>` is really a bad idea (because your `I`  is much less readable).

> Is it possible therefore to typedef a preprocessor directive?

**No** that is not possible...

However, remember that you can always *generate* C code by other means (from other sources). In your case, I believe it would be a bad idea in practice, but you might consider using some *other* preprocessor -perhaps [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp) or [m4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/)- (or some script, perhaps even a simple [awk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) one) to generate your `foo.c` file from e.g. some `foo.mahendra` one; then you'll modify your build procedure accordingly (if you use [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html) for [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation), you'll just add a dependency and a rule for that).

Read about the [C preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor). Today, it is generally part of the compiler. In the previous century, it was a separate program `/lib/cpp`. Read documentation of [GNU cpp](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/). Read also more about [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29), e.g. the (draft) standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), and some sites like [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c) one.

BTW, sometimes it is worth looking at the outcome of the preprocessor. Given some file `foo.c`  you might run (assuming that [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) is your compiler) `gcc -C -E foo.c > foo.i` (perhaps with additional [preprocessing options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html), like `-I/usr/local/include`, just after `gcc`) to get into `foo.i` the preprocessed form of `foo.c`. That preprocessed `foo.i` file is a textual file that you can inspect with some [editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor) or [pager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_pager).

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to use a typedef to alias a preprocessor directive. `typedef` is a keyword, handled by the compiler, not the preprocessor. The preprocessor removes comments from your code and replaces the preprocessor directives such as `#include` with the appropriate output. When you compile a c program there are really three things that happen:

1. First, the preprocessor removes the comments from your code and replaces the corresponding preprocessor directives such as `#include` with the appropriate preprocessor output.
2. Then, the compiler takes the preprocessed code and outputs the compiled code into object files.
3. Lastly, the linker processes the compiled code, combines the object files into one executable file if needed and links the executable file with the necessary libraries.

So although you can't use typedef to alias a preprocessor directive, you can (although you really probably shouldn't) do something like this:

uselessTypedef.h

```
int NUMBER
```

uselessTypedef.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

// note the whitespace between the typedef, #include and the semicolon
// typedef #include "uselessTypedef.h"; doesn't compile because of the way the preprocessor and compiler handle things
typedef
#include "uselessTypedef.h"
;

NUMBER main(NUMBER argc, char* argv[])
{
    NUMBER myint = 12345;
    printf("value of NUMBER myint: %d\n", myint);
    return 0;
}
```

this code compiles and prints `value of NUMBER myint: %d\n`

The compiler never sees the following code:

```
typedef
#include "uselessTypedef.h"
;
```

Instead, the compiler sees this:

```
typedef
int NUMBER
;
```

The compiler ignores whitespace, so that code is equivelent to `typedef int NUMBER;`

Answer (score 0):

(`#include`) is an pre-processor macros and are lexical replacement tool for "including external file". Preprocessor are agnostic of language and have no understanding and what you are trying to do.

On the other hand `typedef` is a feature that lets you create your own alias for types. A `typedef`, in spite of the name, does not define a new type; it merely creates a new name for an existing type. For example, given:

```
typedef int my_int;
```

`my_int` is a new name for `int`; `my_int` and `int` are *exactly* the same type. Similarly, given the `struct` definition above, you can write:

```
typedef struct foo foo;
```

The type already has a name, `struct foo`.  The `typedef` declaration gives the same type a new name, `foo`.

Comment: `#include` is a preprocessing directive not macro.